# How to use hover property with another item?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got stuck on something.

I have the list and when I hover over the list elements (in the hover feature) I want another button in that list element to appear and when I move the mouse over it, I want that button to disappear.

What I am trying to do is to be able to fix the list elements and make the fix button (push_pin) on the list active, passive when it goes over it.

```
 $(".dashboard_li").mouseover(
            function () {
                $('.pin_false').css("display", "block"); 
            } 
        ); 
        $(".dashboard_li").mouseout(
            function () {
                $('.pin_false').css("display", "none");
            }
        );
```

**I can do it this way, but I must show its '.pin_false' class no matter which element I am on.**

*All '.pin_false' elements are now active or passive when you roll over any list element.*

Comment: Can you replicate the problem in a JSFiddle please. Lets see your HTML.

Comment: You should really manage hover states with CSS. That said, hover within a hover sounds like horrible user experience. Extra bad if its ever on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**thanks for your answers. I solved it as follows;**

I gave '.dashboard_li' and '.pin_false' a unique ID. Every time I hover over '.dashboard_li' I took the unique ID on it and defined it as 'ID.' To '.pin_false'. And I did my job as follows.
Thanks everyone :)

```
            $(".dashboard_li").mouseover(
                function (e) {
                    var id = $(this).attr("id");
                    var newId = id.substring(8, id.length);
                    var pin_value = "#pin_" + newId;
                    $(pin_value).css("display", "block");
                }
            );
            $(".dashboard_li").mouseout(
                function () {
                    $('.pin_false').css("display", "none");
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS Solution:

```css
.pin_false {
    display: none;
}

.dashboard_li:hover .pin_false {
    display: block;
}
```

This will ensure that only the element with the class `pin_false` that is a child of the `dashboard_li` element being hovered over will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a pseudo class in CSS defining `display:visible` and `display :none`,
and in jQuery add/remove the pseudo class

Answer (score 0):

In order to only affect the `.dashboard_li` element that was moused over, you should use the target of the `mouseover` event to scope your `.pin_false` query:

```
$(".dashboard_li").mouseover(function(mouseoverEvent) {
  $(mouseoverEvent.currentTarget).find('.pin_false').css("display", "block")
});
$(".dashboard_li").mouseout(function(mouseoutEvent) {
  $(mouseoutEvent.currentTarget).find('.pin_false').css("display", "none")
});
```

That being said, I think John Warren's pure CSS answer is the optimal solution.